# Allocate vs construct an array of ints using operator new and placement new

Tags: c++, new-operator, delete-operator, placement-new

Hello to understand more `placement new`, `operator new`, expression `delete`.. and separating the initialization from construction, I've tried this example:

```
int main(){

    int* p = static_cast<int*>(operator new[](10 * sizeof(int)));
    p = new(p)int[10];

    for(int i = 0; i != 10; ++i)
        p[i] = i * 7;

    for(int i = 0; i != 10; ++i)
        std::cout << p[i] << ", ";
    operator delete[](p);

}
```

- I've compiled it and run it and it works fine and checked it using Valgrind for memory leaks and nothing bad is reported. So is it how separate initialization from allocation?
- What I am not sure about is that I used operator delete to free memory of the dynamic array but didn't destroy it (there is no placement delete). So is there some bad thing in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted, there is no `placement delete`. When using `placement new`, you have to call destructors manually, eg:

```cpp
void* mem = operator new[](10 * sizeof(T));
T* p = new(mem) T[10];
...
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    p[i].~T();
operator delete[](mem);
```

Where `T` is the desired element type.

Calling destructors is not very important for POD types, like `int`, but it is important for non-POD types, like `std::string`, etc, to avoid leaks.

Comment: You have to be careful with code like this.  Some implementations of placement  `new []` add an 'array count' prefix to the array of newly constructed objects which throws off the space calculation for said array.  You are also assuming that the value returned by `new(p) T[10]` is equal to `p`.  Again, this is not always true.  Because of this, it is better to call the non-array form of placement `new` in a loop.  Then (provided you do it right), nothing can go wrong.